# Perform segue from main view on container view

Tags: objective-c

I seem to be unable to understand how to go about this. I have a button on my main view. This view contains a container view. I would like the button on the main view to make the container view segue to another view. I have set up an identifier for the segue, which goes from containerView1 to containerView2. This is a push-segue. The identifier is pushSegue.

On the button on the main view I have tried this:

```
- (IBAction)btnChangeLocation:(UIButton *)sender {
  UIViewController *a = [[ContainerView1 alloc]init];
  [a performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushSegue" sender:nil]; 
}
```

I have successfully performed this segue from within containerView1, by just placing within it, and performing the segue from there. It works just fine then.

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(UIButton *)sender {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushSegue" sender:nil]; 
}
```

But how would I go if I wanted to trigger the segue on the containerView1, from the button on the main view?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I would also like to be able to perform the same segue, from a container view, that is within the container view.

Just to summarize.

MainView----->ContainerView1-->pushSegue--->ContainerView2

ContaainerView1 has a subContainerView, which also has a button, which causes ContainerView1 to segue into ContainerView2. This button and the button on the MainView does the same thing really, just from different "locations".

EDIT: Added a picture to help explain. http://tinypic.com/r/maxpp2/8

Comment: If you're using a pushSegue, I'm expecting a UINavigationController somewhere. Could you share your project somehow?

Comment: I added a picture. I could share the Xcode project too, but I'll need to clean it up a bit first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `UIViewController *a = [[ContainerView1 alloc]init];` you are instantiating a new ContainerView1 controller. That won't help you; you need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` on the instance already created.

Depending on how your Storyboard and code are set up, you need to find a way to get a hold of the embedded view controller.

For this set up:
[image]

You could do something like this in the main (hosting) view controller:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *childView;
@property (weak,nonatomic) UINavigationController *container;

...    

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"embedContainer1"]) {
        self.container = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}

-(IBAction)doIt:(id)sender {
    [self.container.viewControllers[0] performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

By implementing `prepareForSegue:sender:`, you're able to get a reference to the child viewcontroller; cleaner then going through the array of `childViewControllers` IMHO.

Comment: okey, thanks. I am sorry for being such a noob, but could you elaborate?

Comment: Ok, so I did try this and it worked for the button on the main view, but I would like to to it from a method, so that the same code can be called from subviews and the main view. I did try to do it this way, which again works from the button on the main view, but not from the subviews.
- (void)changeView:(NSString *)where
`{
    UINavigationController *a = self.childViewControllers[0];
    UINavigationController *b = a.childViewControllers[0];  
    [b performSegueWithIdentifier:where sender:self];
}`